# "Invalid JWT: Failed audience check." Error when trying to get OAuth Token from Google

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt

I'm trying to get an OAuth2 token from google and keep getting this response:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Invalid JWT: Failed audience check. The right audience is https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token?grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&amp;assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJ1cGRhdGUtbG9jYXRpb24tZGF0YUB0b3RlbWljLWd1aWxkLTEyOTIyMC5pYW0uZ3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50LmNvbSIsInNjb3BlIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlYXBpcy5jb20vYXV0aC9wbHVzLmJ1c2luZXNzLm1hbmFnZSIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lmdvb2dsZWFwaXMuY29tL29hdXRoMi92NC90b2tlbiIsImlhdCI6MTQ2MzY4MjEwOSwiZXhwIjoxNDYzNjg1NjQ5fQ==.a09YUnpiY0FZZFZDUm5PaC91ZkV6ZUtJNGp4WWRWcHY3eFhHNVBXTmw2TGNjZ0JKZThTS2pENitldGNqZzFPMlRRMmNEWWx0aHBNU2k4NS9GeVhnQXdaMHRXVTVEbmcxcXFXQzFRYlp6NmNTZFNlcUt3TElGZjRLeHJCTTgxcVBmVSttQTM0dmprTGtSeEVsWC8vNGpTNDdYM0dobEk2THJOL2xOa2tXcnpEZlk2K1QrNk5OSndyTXhOaTZmcFdXQ09KVE9Gd0tVSnZjYnR1VWNLYnVXbzBqVEhqL056aHBPbkROVW1SSEpYY2JpU3VxVWdRai9PZldiR1p5bzJFK3ZtRzQ5NXdmdDdMMXJkQWdMZkZPcitpeWZVd1FneXVmZFUrRGd1dlZPOWdZSENrS1Fnd0tZb0tUbjNIU29Bcm13OE9OL0RFdkVPM2N2YjhTbFoxbjhRPT0="
}
```

The docs for the service account (which I'm using) are here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests

They say:

"A descriptor of the intended target of the assertion. When making an access token request this value is always https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token."

So when I form my Claim Set, it looks like this:

```
{"iss":"********.iam.gserviceaccount.com","scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage","aud":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token","iat":1463683812,"exp":1463687352}
```

Does anyone know what might be causing my audience check to fail and what I should be using as that value?  Is it possible that other parts of my Token request are incorrect and it just says my audience check is failing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like your Client code is passing the parameters to the token endpoint as query parameters instead of the required POST parameters.

Comment: @Brad, did that work? I'm getting the same error when I send "grant_type" and "assertion" as query parameters. However, when I send them as POST parameters, I get 

    {
      "error": "invalid_request",
      "error_description": "Required parameter is missing: grant_type"
    }

Comment: @SamDevx    What value did you give to grant_type and how did you make the POST request eventually?

Answer (score 6):

As of now (Feb 7, 2020), the `aud` value is

```
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
```

[Link.](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) Screenshot below.

---

At the time of the OP, it was

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
```

[image: Google ID platform screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

For me sending those params in body instead of using them in query worked.

[image: Postman send POST example]

My Claim Set:

```
var now = ~~(Date.now() / 1000);
var data = {
  "iss": "xxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction",
  "aud": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
  "iat": now,
  "exp": now + 3600
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my jwt was incorrect, with custom url, because I used proxy

I monkeypatch libs for custom request but stock jwt, and all worked