# Google Rest API: "Invalid JWT: Failed Audience Check"? I am using audience field API suggests

Tags: dart, google-api, jwt, google-calendar-api

I am attempting to connect to Google's REST API (for Google Calendars) using a JWT. I have followed the instructions up to and including [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests). When I send a post request with my JWT (with `grant_type` and `assertion` in the body per previous StackOverflow posts), I get an error:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Invalid JWT: Failed audience check. The right audience is https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"
}
```

My code is short so I'll post it in full (sans private details) below. I'm using the `jaguar_jwt` library and modeled my JWT generation off of their sample code. I have create a service account and I believe followed all instructions up until the aforementioned point in Google's documentation.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:jaguar_jwt/jaguar_jwt.dart';

String generateJWT() {
  final String privateKey = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----.********=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";

  final claimSet = new JwtClaim(
      issuer: 'google-api@**********.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
      audience: <String>['https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token'],
      otherClaims: <String,dynamic>{
        "scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
        "access_type": "offline"
      },
      maxAge: const Duration(minutes: 60));

  String token = issueJwtHS256(claimSet, privateKey);
  // print(token);

  return token;
}

void sendJWT(String jwt) async {
  var client = new http.Client();
  try {
    String googleUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";

    var requestBody = {'grant_type':'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
                        'assertion':'$jwt',
                        "access_type": "offline"
                      };

    await client.post(googleUri, body: requestBody)
          .then((value) => print(value.body));

  } finally {
    client.close();
  }
}

main(List<String> arguments) {
  sendJWT(generateJWT());
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37331910/invalid-jwt-failed-audience-check-error-when-trying-to-get-oauth-token-from

Comment: No, I referenced the answer here in my post.... "with `grant_type` and `assertion` in the body per previous StackOverflow posts"